# .NET Identity 2.0 with custom salted passwords

Tags: asp.net-identity-2, password-encryption

I'm trying to switch to .NET Identity from an old custom membership provider in an existing MVC application, and maintain dapper as the ORM, not EntityFramework which comes out of the box.

I'm stuck at trying to implement my own `IPasswordHasher`, as I need the existing credentials to work. In `HashPassword` I want to return a SHA-computed hash of the cleartext input combined with a user-specific salt, but the method only receives the clear text value, and no reference to the user for which a login is attempted.

Where can I get this salt? Or am I going at this in the wrong way?

Comment: So you need to pass password and salt to `IPasswordHasher`? Can you modify DB structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do pretty much the same thing for migration. And the recommended [migration article](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) provides the solution for your problem.

You need to merge old password hash with the salt into one `Password` field, separated by a special symbol (in the article it was `|`, but you can choose your own separator).

And then `PasswordHasher` should check the password for that special symbol, and if it is present separate salt from the password and apply the hashing.

Here is a code snippet from the linked above article, though I've removed some noise for checking of plain-text password storage. This presumes that your hash is stored in format `SH1hash|salt`

```
public class SQLPasswordHasher : PasswordHasher
{
    public override string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return base.HashPassword(password);
    }

    public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string  hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        string[] passwordProperties = hashedPassword.Split('|');
        if (passwordProperties.Length != 2)
        {
            // use default Identity implementation
            return base.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, providedPassword);
        }
        else
        {
            string passwordHash = passwordProperties[0];
            string salt = passwordProperties[1];
            if (String.Equals(EncryptPassword(providedPassword, salt), passwordHash, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded;
            }
            else
            {
                return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
            }
        }
    }

    //This is copied from the existing SQL provider
    private string EncryptPassword(string pass, string salt)
    {
        byte[] bIn = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
        byte[] bSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        byte[] bRet = null;

        HashAlgorithm hm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
        if (hm is KeyedHashAlgorithm)
        {
            KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = (KeyedHashAlgorithm)hm;
            if (kha.Key.Length == bSalt.Length)
            {
                kha.Key = bSalt;
            }
            else if (kha.Key.Length < bSalt.Length)
            {
                byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, 0, bKey.Length);
                kha.Key = bKey;
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] bKey = new byte[kha.Key.Length];
                for (int iter = 0; iter < bKey.Length; )
                {
                    int len = Math.Min(bSalt.Length, bKey.Length - iter);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bKey, iter, len);
                    iter += len;
                }
                kha.Key = bKey;
            }
            bRet = kha.ComputeHash(bIn);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] bAll = new byte[bSalt.Length + bIn.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bSalt, 0, bAll, 0, bSalt.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bIn, 0, bAll, bSalt.Length, bIn.Length);
            bRet = hm.ComputeHash(bAll);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bRet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going for something nearly identical to this (currently performing the hash+salt concat in `UserStore.GetPasswordHashAsync` if the password hash length complies with my old hashes), but this is neat as well. I might switch to performing the concat directly in the database once we go live, so that I can get rid of the Salt field immediately.